# Who is responsible for Microsoft Updates on Azure VM

Tags: azure

On my Azure VM (Windows Server 2016) I get usual `Updates are Ready` notice that I initially ignored thinking the Azure will automatically install these updates. But updates are not installed and I keep getting the above message. When I open the message it shows the following message box. Do I have to install these updates or I should still wait for Azure to do the job? This [official Azure article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/maintenance-and-updates) is not clear to me.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure provides the platform and the underlying topology. You do everything at the OS level (updates included) and above.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it would be ok to stop the VM from Azure Portal and let the Updates running in the background on VM?

Answer (score 0):

Azure VM wont install updates automatically. You are responsible for it.

Azure periodically performs updates to improve the reliability, performance, and security of the host infrastructure for virtual machines. - Microsoft

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/maintenance-and-updates